# MongoDB-PySpark: StringType has no matching BsonValue

Tags: python, mongodb, pyspark

I'm trying to write data to Mongodb, and I'm having the following error:

```
StringType has no matching BsonValue. Error: For input string: "457133333333672364913"
```

while saving the dataframe to mongodb using pyspark.

To save the dataframe I'm using:

```
(df
   .write
   .format("mongodb")
   .mode("append")
   .option("convertJson", "any")
   .option("database", "test")
   .option("collection", "mongo_collection")
   .save())
```

The column giving the error is an `ArrayType(StringType())`

Using Python3.9 and pyspark 3.4.0

I've searched online but I'm not finding anything related.

Comment: can you show your dataframe schema and mongodb table datatypes use print(df.schema)

Comment: the schema of the dataframe is related to the schema of the column: `StructType([StructField('column_x', ArrayType(StringType(), False), True)])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the error removing the option:

```
.option("convertJson", "any")
```

that was causing the error in the conversion in Bson.